# getElementById and creating divs dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm just wondering how i could make this code more efficient. I feel like there is a lot of code here to accomplish a simple task. But i'm not sure how to better it? Is there a way to dynamically create divs? Or is tehre a way to reduce the number of "getElementById" calls i make?

Comment: Have you tried javascript library, such as JQuery?

Comment: I would use jQuery, object properties and loops.

Comment: In a nutshell, use jQuery for the sake of simpleness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a number of improvements you might make, whether it's in terms of speed, readability, or maintainability. Here's a list of some off the top of my head:

1. Cache the note element in a variable if you're going to reuse it. This makes your code faster since you don't have to grab the element again to use it.

   ```
   var noteDiv = document.getElementById("A");
   noteDiv.note = notes[9];
   noteDiv.onmouseover = displayIt;
   ```
2. Instead of repeating your code so much, you could iterate over something that keeps track of your notes. In this example I am using an array of ids and an object containing the ids and notes as property-value pairs.

   ```
   var noteDivs = ["Middle", "D", "E", "F", ... ]
   // note that the order you put notes in here does not matter
   var notes = { Middle: "Middle C",
                 D: "D",
                 E: "E",
                 F: "F",
                 ... }
   function MakingNoise () {
       for (var i = 0; i < noteDivs.length ; i++) {
           document.getElementById(noteDivs[i]).note = notes[noteDivs[i]];
           document.getElementById(noteDivs[i]).onmouseover = displayIt;
       }
   }
   ```
3. The `box` element can be cached as well through a global variable. Might not be good style, but this should be faster than getting it from the DOM each time.

   ```
   var screen=document.getElementById("box"); 
   function displayIt() {
       if (this.note && screen) {
           screen.innerHTML += note + "  ";
       }
   }
   ```

Putting everything together, you have the following:

```
var screen=document.getElementById("box"); 
var noteDivs = ["Middle", "D", "E", "F", ... ]
var notes = { Middle: "Middle C",
              D: "D",
              E: "E",
              F: "F",
              ... }

function MakingNoise () {
    for (var i = 0; i < noteDivs.length ; i++) {
        var noteDiv = document.getElementById(noteDivs[i]);
        noteDiv.note = notes[noteDivs[i]];
        noteDiv.onmouseover = displayIt;
    }
}
function displayIt() {
    if (this.note && screen) {
        screen.innerHTML += note + "  ";
    }
}
```

It might even be better to keep your `notes` array instead of using the `notes` object I have above, as long as you make sure the order is the same as the `noteDivs` array. It will be faster, but also slightly more work to maintain. You would also need to have one `div` for each element in `notes`, which you currently don't have.

Answer (score 1):

One solutions that doesn't use jQuery or any such library might look like this:

```
var notes = ["Middle C","C#","D","D#","E","F","F#","G", "G#", "A", "A#", "B", "C"];
var note, div, name;

var myKeys = document.getElementById("myKeys");


for (var i = 0, len = notes.length; i < len; i++) {
    note = notes[i];
    name = note.replace(/\s/g, "").replace(/#/g, "S");
    div = document.createElement("DIV");
    div.className = name;
    div.id = name;
    div.note = note;
    div.appendChild(document.createTextNode(note));
    div.onmouseover = displayIt;
    myKeys.appendChild(div);
}​
```

You can see it in action at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CrossEye/dcUag/1/).

Answer (score 0):

One improvement is to store the DOM element in a variable and re-use it instead of finding it again using getElementById. It's more efficient too.

If you use a framework like jQuery, that would save code as well as you could do chaining.